# Keyboard combination not being registered at all

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon

My machine is a 13 inch Macbook Pro, M1 2020 running on Monteray

I have a problem with this specific keyboard combination: `control + option + up`, which is not registering at all. I found the problem because that keyboard combination is used in [Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com/).

When I tried the combination in a keyboard tester site, (e.g. [this one](https://en.key-test.ru/)), or tried to set a keyboard shortcut under Keyboard > Shortcuts preference, it does not work.

The odd thing is that only this specific combination is not registering. Other similar combinations works fine:

- `control + option + left`
- `control + option + down`
- `control + option + right`

I've tried:

- Unplugging everything and trying the combination on the mac keyboard
- Shutting the machine down and starting it again after waiting for at least a minute
- Killing most of the background apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found the problem.

Turns out it was one of the shortcuts in [Beardie](https://github.com/Stillness-2/beardie) all along, and I didn't kill it when I was killing background apps.